# Android game designing

Tags: android

i am new in android field m searching n learning android from last 1 month nw m having a problum with android game designing....
for the android concept and application designing i find ***Android 3.0 Application 
Development Cookbook***  and 
**http://developer.android.com** 
very help full now m having a good knowledge of android application designing but as i want to design game so i want any book or site who explain me complete concept of game designing in android step by step.

Comment: From StackOverflow FAQ: What questions should I **not** ask here? *Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.*

Comment: Yeah, but he's asking for the title, not the entire book ;)

Comment: Ooops wheres my coffee. My bad. Misleading title at least then. ;)

Comment: Please refrain from posting duplicate questions. There are already [too many duplicates of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+game+design)

Answer (score 4):

I have [Beginning Android Games](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430230428) by one of the guys behind [libgdx](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/). I found it really easy to work through. It covers 2d game programming pretty well and even gets into some of the basic open gl stuff.

It gave me enough knowledge to branch off and start a project of my own with confidence.

Answer (score 1):

Searching using Google, i came across a few tutorials and books that would be helpful:

http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/beginning-android-game

http://www.rbgrn.net/content/54-getting-started-android-game-development

http://www.droidnova.com/android-3d-game-tutorial-part-i,312.html

Other questions similar to yours on StackOverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837925/good-book-for-android-game-development

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885533/where-to-start-game-programming-for-android

Go through them, and try studying the basis of 3D graphics, it will be very helpful, like concepts of Rendering, rasterization, and try learning openGL, it'll boost your concepts specific to game development, also look at a few game engines and how they work, try Unity3D for start.

http://unity3d.com/

Learning game development (in your case specific to Android, but i am talking generally) is fun but tough. If you start enjoying it, you'll be an expert in a very short time.

And search before posting here, this question has been answered in detail.

Comment: thank u....i will keep ur suggestion in my mind